# How to show multiple data from SQLite database inside ListView in Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-listview

I am a newcomer to Android development.

I can't figure out how to get Android Studio to just take what's in my SQLite database and paste its contents into a listview. I thought there would be a easy way after Log the output but can able to display everything there is in a database in a ListView but it appears to be much more in a different way of doing it.

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText nameEditText;
    EditText phoneEditText;
    ListView updateListView;

    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        nameEditText = findViewById(R.id.nameEditText);
        phoneEditText = findViewById(R.id.phoneEditText);
        updateListView = findViewById(R.id.updatedListView);



        sqLiteDatabase = this.openOrCreateDatabase("Contact", MODE_PRIVATE, null);

        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users(name VARCHAR, phone INT(11),id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY)");


    }


    public void OnClick(View view) {


        if (nameEditText.equals("") || phoneEditText.equals("")) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Fields shouldn't be empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {

            sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("INSERT INTO users(name, phone) VALUES('" + nameEditText.getText().toString() + "','" + phoneEditText.getText().toString() + "')");

            Cursor c = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM users", null);
            int nameIndex = c.getColumnIndex("name");
            int phoneIndex = c.getColumnIndex("phone");
            int idIndex = c.getColumnIndex("id");
            if (c != null && c.getCount() > 0) {
                c.moveToFirst();
                for (int i = 0; i < c.getCount(); i++) {
                    String str = c.getString(0);

                    String UpdatedList = (c.getString(nameIndex));
                    String phonelist = (c.getString(phoneIndex));

                    String list = (UpdatedList+phonelist);
                    ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>(Integer.parseInt(list));
                    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,arrayList);
                    updateListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);              


                    Log.i("User Name", c.getString(nameIndex));
                    Log.i("userResults - age", Integer.toString(c.getInt(phoneIndex)));
                    Log.i("userResults - id", Integer.toString(c.getInt(idIndex)));
                    c.moveToNext();
                }




            }
        }
    }
    }
```

My Logput

```
2020-01-22 20:22:48.353 28783-28783/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2020-01-22 20:22:48.357 28783-28783/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.mysqlapp, PID: 28783
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:390)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6669)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6638)
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:789)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:26145)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6898)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:537)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:385)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6669) 
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6638) 
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:789) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:26145) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6898) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:537) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858) 
     Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:627)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:650)
        at com.example.mysqlapp.MainActivity.OnClick(MainActivity.java:65)
```

Comment: Can you more specify your issue/query ??

Comment: first `nameEditText.equals("")` wrong way of checking empty edittext, use this instead `nameEditText.getText().toString().trim().equals("")`

Comment: try posting your activity_main.xml here the error saying cannot execute the onClick function of the button

Comment: and its better to create a database helper class for your sqlite transaction. its easy, neat and comfortable.

Answer (score 1):

call setAdapter method outside, after you declare whole arrayList from sql, outside of for loop

Comment: Madonabulia: we encourage helpers here to write more than a sentence in answers. Very short contributions are better as comments (and if you prefer short contributions, you only need 50 reputation points to be able to do that). Very short or unclear answers are sometimes deleted by the Review Queue.

Comment: @Shivas: notwithstanding my advice to Madonabulia, "not working" is not a helpful response. Only you can see your screen, so you need to let your helper know _how_ it does not work. What observations can you make? Do you see any errors? If you merely say "it does not work" it will put the onus on someone else to ask you more questions, and at that point they will be guessing about what you need to do.